# Prevent function from firing twice when bound to input on focus and click

Tags: jquery, binding

I'm attempting to get an event to fire on both `click` and `focus`, however I only want it to fire once. When I click inside an input, it fires twice (clicking and focusing). How can I prevent this?

```
$('input').on('focus click', function(){
    console.log('fired');
});
```

Comment: FWIW, I've updated my original answer with a general-purpose debouncer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead. That will only allow the event to fire once, but will also remove the bind once it has been fired:

```
$('input').one('focus click', function(){
    console.log('fired');
});
```

If you need to keep the bind you will have to keep track of the state of the mouse button and the current target that triggered the `mousedown`:

```
var mouseDown, currentTarget;
$('input').on({
    "mousedown mouseup": function (e) {
        mouseDown = e.type === "mousedown";
        currentTarget = e.target;
    },
    "focus click": function (e) {
        if (mouseDown && currentTarget === e.target) return;
        console.log('fired');
    }
});
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/rBzqg/1/).

Comment: But then that removes the binding... which isn't what I want.

Comment: @kylex Added `stopImmediatePropagation` method as well, which should work... I would say that it's a bug that it doesn't. Going to research some more because I kind of dislike T.J's solution, even though it works.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall: [`stopImmediatePropagation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-stopImmediatePropagation) stops propagation of **that event** (e.g., `click`) to other handlers. It doesn't do anything to stop other events the browser is also going to fire as a by-product of the current event (e.g., `focus`).

Comment: Just realized another problem with the last method. It doesn't work properly if two `focus` events are fired after one another, since it won't register the second `focus`. @kylex may I ask why you need to bind to click at all, since a click will trigger focus, it shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: @MarcusEkwall, I'm binding to both because it's not just input that activates it. It could be a div or span. I only showed input because that is the tag that causes issues.

Comment: @kylex Okey! Revised my answer. It now includes a fully working solution.

Answer (score 8):

A little hysteresis might be an option. Basically record the last time you responded to either event and ignore subsequent events within a guard time.

You *could* use jQuery's `data` for this (example at end of answer), but I prefer this: A general-purpose debouncer:

[Live Example using `click` and `focus`](http://jsbin.com/uqecok/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/uqecok/1/edit)

```
$("#field").on("click focus", debounce(100, function(e) {
  // Event occurred, but not with 100ms of the previous one
}));
```

The `debouncer` function:

```
// debounce - debounces a function call
//
// Usage: var f = debounce([guardTime, ] func);
//
// Where `guardTime` is the interval during which to suppress
// repeated calls, and `func` in the function to call.
// You use the returned function instead of `func` to get
// debouncing;
//
// Example: Debouncing a jQuery `click` event so if it happens
// more than once within a second (1,000ms), subsequent ones
// are ignored:
//
//    $("selector").on("click", debounce(1000, function(e) {
//      // Click occurred, but not within 1000ms of previous
//    });
//
// Both `this` and arguments are passed through.
function debounce(guardTime, func) {
  var last = 0;

  if (typeof guardTime === "function") {
    func = guardTime;
    guardTime = 100;
  }
  if (!guardTime) {
    throw "No function given to debounce";
  }
  if (!func) {
    throw "No func given to debounce";
  }

  return function() {
    var now = +new Date();
    if (!last || (now - last) > guardTime) {
      last = now;
      return func.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
}
```

(The name "debouncer" is a common term for something that uses hysteresis to rate-limit inputs. IIRC, it comes from "switch debouncer" which is a (very) simple circuit used to avoid triggering an action hundreds of times as a mechanical-throw electric switch transitions from being open to being closed and vice-versa, since when the contacts get in proximity, there can be a lot of closed/open/closed/open/closed/open chatter before the switch hits steady-state. This chatter is called "[bouncing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce)," hence, "debouncer.")

---

The approach just using jQuery's `data`:

```
$('input').on('focus click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var now = +new Date();
    var lastClicked = $this.data("lastClicked");
    if (lastClicked && (now - lastClicked) < 100) {
        // Don't do anything
        return;
    }
    $this.data("lastClicked", now);

    // Do the work
});
```

Comment: +1 a bit hacky, but a solid work around.(i would still be aware of edge cases)

Comment: The problem with using a hysteresis or debouncer is that if you click the `input` and hold the button for longer then 100ms, it will trigger for both `click` and `focus`.

Comment: underscore js has an implementation of debounce see [here](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I couldn't find any other answers like what solved my problem. So I'm posting it here for anyone who happens to run into this problem in 2015.

```
$('#menu-button').on('click focus', function() {
  if(!$(this).is(':focus')) { // 1
    // Do stuff once
  }
  else {
    $this.blur(); // 2
  }
});
```

1. This fires the event on click only. I'm not sure what's going on behind the scenes, so maybe someone can explain this to me, but tabbing and focus appear untouched and working 100%.
2. This un-focuses the selected object, but it sets the focus path back to the top of the document. I leave this here so I can click the selected element again to disable a menu. I'm still looking for a fix to keep the focus path.

Edit: Better way:

```
$('#menu-button').on('click focus', function(event) {
  if(event.type === 'focus') { // 1
    // Do stuff once
  }
});
```

1. Click will trigger a focus, but focus won't ever trigger a click. So just run code on the focus event.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your post. I like your 'Better way'. But I'm using 1.7.2 version of jQuery that gives me 'focusin' instead of 'focus'. Thank you for one line solution.